# border-image doesn't wrap around the entire border

Tags: html, border, css

How would I get the image that I'm using to wrap around the entire border? It only shows up on the top and bottom. I used border-image.com to scale it down, but I can only get the desired result on either top or bottom, or left and right borders. I basically want the image to wrap around repeatedly in a consistent manner as is (company's logo repeated throughout all the borders) without having to stretch, manipulate, or scale it in any way. I would really appreciate any help ? 
[Here's what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/6MghG/)

HTML:

```
 <div id="outer_container">
 ...
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer_container {
height: 1495px;
width: 925px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #E7EAF5;
border-radius: 15px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 38px 38px 38px 38px;
border-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/81/81/) 81 0 fill repeat stretch;
}
```

Comment: I understand now that border-image doesn't wrap around the entire border. Are there any other ways to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use divs to accomplish this:

HTML:

```
<div id="div-top"></div>
<div id="div-left"></div>
<div id="container">
</div>
<div id="div-right"></div>
<div id="div-bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div-top,
#div-bottom {
    width: 925px;
    height: 81px;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/81/81/') repeat-x;
    clear: both;
}

#div-left,
#div-right {
    width: 81px;
    height: 1495px;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/81/81/') repeat-y;
}

#div-left,
#div-right,
#container {
    float: left;
}

#container {
    height: 1495px;
    width: 763px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #E7EAF5;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6MghG/1/
(Note that you'd need to enlarge the fiddle preview box for it to show up correctly; it should work fine in a browser window.)

Another advantage of this is wider browser compatibility - for example, IE10 does not support border-image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the 0 that you are adding after the 81. If you remove the number the border will apply to all the borders

```
border-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/81/81/) 40 fill repeat stretch;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4rjw6/

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to specify the properties of your border one by one. I tried this in Chrome with your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6MghG/2/

```
border-image-source:url(http://lorempixel.com/81/81/); /* where the image comes from */
border-image-slice: 33.3%; /* chop that image into 9 pieces each one-ninth the total area */
border-image-width: 50px; /* just how wide to draw the border. Overrides border-width. */
border-image-repeat: round; /* change the image size along the edges to make it fit neatly */
```

And that looked OK to me. You have to take the logo you want to use and put nine copies of it in a single image to use this technique.